# Broken link in "This user no recent positive reputation changes"

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, help-center

I noticed that when viewing a user's profile, if they have no recent positive reputation changes, the link that's displayed is broken. I hate to pick on anyone in particular so I just found a [random user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5090/mitja) to demonstrate this issue. If you look at this user's profile you will see

> This user no recent positive [reputation changes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5090/$helpLink)

The help link points to `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/{userid}/$helpLink`. I'm pretty sure this is supposed to link to the help center, but as it is right now, clicking the link does nothing. This appears to be an issue on *all* sites.

There is also a typo here. It should read:

> This user *has* no recent positive [reputation changes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5090/$helpLink)

Comment: It's also missing the word "has", heh.

Comment: The return of the $!

Comment: Your suggested fix of the typo has a typo

Comment: This sentence no verb.

Comment: @Walter That is probably better than this sentence, which has no

Comment: If I could share with my wife even 1% of the humor I find on meta, and she had some chance of actually appreciating it, I'd laugh out loud instead of inside more often.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd There seem to be $AnAwfulLot$ of #SubstitutionBugs# lately...

Comment: @michaelb958 yeah, it's all related to templates! :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This been fixed in build 2013.8.1.1300 (meta) / 2013.8.1.910 (sites). Turns out the link template was in need of `$`...

Comment: Another problem fixed by throwing $ at it.