# "This user has no recent positive reputation changes" link should go to changes or be renamed

Tags: bug, profile-page, hyperlinks

It looks like when [Broken link in "This user no recent positive reputation changes"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191298/broken-link-in-this-user-no-recent-positive-reputation-changes) was fixed (or later on), the link was made to point to general help about reputation, and you now have to click the word "Reputation" above it to find the reputation changes.

There are still two UX problems with this link ([example profile](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/96650/nh?tab=topactivity)):

1. The link text is "reputation changes", but it links to general information about reputation. Whereas the link that shows you reputation changes is simply named "Reputation".  This seems backwards.
2. (minor) There is no period at the end of the sentence.

Number 1 should be fixed by either swapping the link destinations or pulling "changes" out of the hyperlink, and putting the word changes (or a fontawesome icon that indicates change...) in the upper hyperlink.

Also don't forget to change the "yourself" version: "You have no recent positive reputation changes".